# Fetch particular data from the sql table

Tags: sql

I have following table schema:

```
UserID | LoginTime
```

Now, I want to fetch those `userid` which haven't not logged in the past 7 days using the `LoginTime` column from the table.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only one record for each user

```
select UserID
from table
where LoginTime < dateadd(dd, -7, getdate())
```

If you have multiple records for one user

```
select UserID
from table
group by UserID
having max(LoginTime) < dateadd(dd, -7, getdate())
```